# Can't sign in to the Apache Tomcat Version 8.5.75

Tags: authentication, tomcat

I have previously installed some older Apache Tomcat. I have already removed they completely([how to remove it](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.4/Installing_Appian_as_a_Windows_Service.html)) and reinstall the Apache Tomcat 8.5 . Now when I try to type `http://localhost:8080/` and try to log in , It doesn't give me to login even I give the correct username and password.

this is my 'tomcat-users.xml'

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">              
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui" />
```

[LogIn image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjRGp.png) help me to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed port number from 8080 t0 8081 and it worked. Go to apache tomcat installation directory and find conf directory in my pc it is
 `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\conf`

Now open the server.xml and change the port number to 8081 and save.

```
<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Now restart the apache tomcat server.